# Why aren't my card box shadows showing in the browser?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5.3.3 to build a small dashboard.
Since I'm using native components on BS, I'm processing the original SASS adding some color changes and some other minor changes.

But I'm having a hard time adding box-shadow to cards as a default property.

My custom.scss

```
// --------------------------------------------------
$input-btn-padding-x:    .9rem;
$input-btn-padding-y:    .45rem;
// -------------------------
$input-btn-padding-x-sm: .8rem;
$input-btn-padding-y-sm: .28rem;
// -------------------------
$input-btn-padding-x-lg: 1rem;
$input-btn-padding-y-lg: .5rem;
// --------------------------------------------------
@import "functions";
@import "variables";
// --------------------------------------------------
$primary:   #907CF5;
$secondary: #6c757d;
$success:   #0acf97;
$info:      #39afd1;
$warning:   #ffbc00;
$danger:    #fa5c7c;
$light:     #eef2f7;
$dark:      #313a46;
// --------------------------------------------------
$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, (
  "primary":   $primary,
  "secondary": $secondary,
  "success":   $success,
  "info":      $info,
  "warning":   $warning,
  "danger":    $danger,
  "light":     $light,
  "dark":      $dark
));
// --------------------------------------------------
$min-contrast-ratio: 2.5;
// --------------------------------------------------
$border-radius:     .15rem;
$border-radius-sm:  .15rem;
$border-radius-lg:  .15rem;
$border-radius-xl:  .15rem;
$border-radius-xxl: .15rem;
// --------------------------------------------------
$body-bg: #fafbfe;
// --------------------------------------------------
$font-family-sans-serif: "Asap", sans-serif;
$font-size-root:         14px;
// --------------------------------------------------
@import "bootstrap";
// --------------------------------------------------
```

It works perfectly!

But when I add:

```
$card-box-shadow: 0 0 34px 0 rgba(154, 161, 171, 0.14);
```

It processes (correctly inside the card component) like

```
--bs-card-box-shadow: 0 0 34px 0 rgba(154, 161, 171, 0.14);
```

But it's not rendered on browser.

What Am I doing wrong?
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As shadows are disabled by default, you need to enable them first, so try setting:

```
$enable-shadows: true;
```

or you can explicitly assign it only to the card component.

see:

> While shadows on components are disabled by default in Bootstrap and
> can be enabled via $enable-shadows,
>
> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/shadows/#examples

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I use both lines `$enable-shadows: true;` and `$card-box-shadow: 0 0 34px 0 rgba(154, 161, 171, 0.14);`, shadows work on cards, but other elements got shadows too. I'm not being able to assign box-shadow only on cards.

Comment: well, I'm not sure how to apply it on single component, which is why I suggested to assign it explicitly.. so, after card box shadow variable, you might then add the `box-shadow` property explicitly: `.card {  box-shadow: var(--bs-card-box-shadow); }` it seems that box shadow is added via mixin, which only adds it if shadows are enabled..https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_card.scss#L39